# Mapbox vector tile source from more tilesets, or layer with more sources?

Tags: mapbox, maplibre-gl, mapbox-vector-tile

I have a huge amount of data to generate into vector tiles, but only the same 10% is changing in the tilesets. The data type is the same, so i cannot separate it into different layers because it would be a big performance loss if i would duplicate all my 150 layers.

I thought the tiles array parameter in the vector tile source provides the capability of merging more vector tiles into one source, but its for a different purpose.

Is there any tricky way to merge more tilesets' data, or more sources into a layer?

Comment: where is the data stored?

Comment: graph postgres database (1table).